# Order-preserving injection between intervals of ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, ordinals

Let $[\alpha, \alpha')$ and $[\beta, \beta')$ be two intervals of ordinals such that $\alpha' - \alpha \leq \beta' - \beta$. Is there an order-preserving injection $f : [\alpha, \alpha') \rightarrow [\beta, \beta')$?

My idea would be the following. Let $i : \alpha' - \alpha \rightarrow \beta' - \beta$ be the inclusion map. Then define $f_1(x) := i(\alpha' - x) + \beta$ or $f_2(x) := \beta + i(\alpha' - x)$. However, I'm not able to show that either of them is injective.

Comment: Every well-ordering $W$ is isomorphic to a unique ordinal $g(W)$, and if  $W$ is a proper initial segment of $W'$ then $g(W)$ is a proper initial segment of $g(W')$ so $g(W)<g(W').$ For $x\in [\alpha, \alpha')$ let  $f(x)=\beta +g([\alpha,x)).$  Suppose $\alpha \le x<x'<\alpha'.$ Then $g([\alpha,x'))\ge g([\alpha,x))+1$ because $[\alpha, x)$ is a proper initial segment of $[\alpha,x').$ Ordinal addition is associative. So $f(x')=\beta +g([\alpha,x'))\ge \beta+(g([\alpha,x))+1)=(\beta+g([\alpha,x))+1=f(x)+1>f(x).$

Comment: A well-ordering cannot be order-isomorphic to a proper initial segment of itself.  This implies the uniqueness of $g(W)$ in my previous comment.